# How do I get rid of inherited SELECTs in Postgres queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres 9.4
I guess, queries like this is not the best approach in terms of database performance:

```
SELECT t.name,
    t.description,
    t.rating,
    t.readme,
    t.id AS userid,
    t.notifications
   FROM ( SELECT "user".name,
            "user".description,
            "user".rating,
            "user".readme,
            "user".id,
            ( SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(notifications.*))) AS array_to_json
                   FROM ( SELECT notification.id,
                            notification.action_type,
                            notification.user_id,
                            notification.user_name,
                            notification.resource_id,
                            notification.resource_name,
                            notification.resource_type,
                            notification.rating,
                            notification.owner
                           FROM notification
                          WHERE (notification.owner = "user".id)
                          ORDER BY notification.created DESC) notifications) AS notifications
           FROM "user") t
```

Column `notification` contains json object with all the matched rows from `notification` table.
How should I rebuild this query to receive data in the same manner? I suppose, I should use `JOIN` commands somehow.
I have request, which utilise more than one inherited `SELECT`.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you actually looked into the explain plan to see if there is a problem with performance?

Comment: yes, i did. It's not much informative without large amounts of real data. Actually, I thought, inherited selects is bad approach by definition and have to be replaced with `JOIN`s or some other commands.

Comment: query derived tables can often be faster than standard joins as filtering can be done prior to any joining (therefore, the SELECT only needs to evaluate on a smaller subset of data) - but that's not really the point. If your tables have strong referential integrity, use the key joins. If you have strong pre-filters of data, use derived tables, then join them via keys.

Comment: Thank you, Trent!  Could you, please, post an example of the query with inherited `JOINs` instead of selects based on my example?

Answer (score 1):

The outermost query only aliases `id` to `userid`.  You can move the alias to the inner query, and omit the outer query entirely.

Then you can create a function to create the notification JSON:

```
create or replace function get_user_notifications(user_id bigint)
returns json language sql as
$$
    select  array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(n)))
    from    (
            select  id
            ,       action_type
            ,       ... other columns from notification ...
            from    notification
                    -- Use function name to refer to parameter not column
            where   user_id = get_user_notifications.user_id 
            order by
                    created desc
            ) n
$$;
```

Now you can write the query as:

```
select  id as userid
,       ... other columns from "user" ...
,       get_user_notifications(id) as notifications
from    "user" u;
```

Which looks a lot better, at the cost of having to maintain Postgres functions.